# How can I select only the 10 previous rows before all rows that sastify a condition?

Tags: r, subset

I have a time series dataset in R environment.
A variable CB_Day is equal to MPD on some dates and 0 on most of the dates.

**I want to delete all rows except the MPD days and the 10 previous days.**

I have tried **subset**, **head()** and **tail()**, but they did not work.

> Can someone tell me what is the right command for deleting records
>   based on my condition in R ?

The result should be the whole table with all other columns. Only rows need wo be deleted.

Comment: Look into `which()`?

Answer (score 2):

If I get it right then something like this should help...

```
# create data where CB_Day is always 0 (please provide reproducible data next time)
df <- data.frame(MPD  = 1:100, CB_Day = rep(0, 100))
# sometimes CB_Day is same as MPD
df$CB_Day[c(20, 70)] <- df$MPD[c(20, 70)]
# Find where both are same
same <- which(df$MPD== df$CB_Day)
# create vectors with "10 rows before CB_Day and MPD are same" to the row where they are same
keep <- sapply(same, function(x){(x-10):x})
# make it a vector instead of a matrix
keep <- unlist(keep)
# select the rows
df[keep, ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. Your example worked perfectly on R, but the variable name is CB_Day and it is sometimes MPD and mostly zero. So it's only one column, that I want to look at.

Comment: @UkëSmajli If I get it right then I simply mixed up the names of the variables? If so, you can edit my post (click edit). Also do consider to check my post if it answers your question.